# Can anyone explain this program in detail

Tags: c++, get, stream, cin

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int SIZE=4;
   char Sentence[SIZE];
   char Sentence2[SIZE];

   cout << "Enter the sentence" <<endl;
   cin >> Sentence;

   cout << "\nThe string read with cin was"
 << endl <<Sentence <<endl;
  char ch = cin.get();

  cout << "Enter the second sentence: "<<endl;
  cin.get(Sentence2,SIZE,'$');
  cout << Sentence2 <<endl;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter the sentence
This is my first sentence

The string read with cin was
This
Enter the second sentence:
is
```

I have just started learning C++ and I am not able to understand this program as well as it's output. Pls can anyone suggest me where to learn it from or explain it in detail .

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: `char` array of size 4 can only fit 3 characters in it, leaving a space for null terminator.

Comment: I don't understand the output of this part  :   cout << "Enter the second sentence: "<<endl;
  cin.get(Sentence2,SIZE,'$');
  cout << Sentence2 <<endl;

Comment: Yes Can u please explain it

Comment: If you ask how `cin.get(Sentence2,SIZE,'$');` works, you can check out the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). Might be a bit hard to read as beginner, but it's worth to try understanding it.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that's rather poorly written code, so you don't need to spend much time trying to understand it.

Comment: I agree with @PeteBecker, this is very poorly written code. My favorite part is asking for a sentence but only allowing for 3 characters. What kind of sentence is that? Although even if the size was fixed or the code was updated to use `std::string` the `cin >> Sentence;` would read the first word not a sentence anyways.

Comment: Trying to put 5 characters into an array that can hold 4 is undefined behavior: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455302/where-c-really-stores-a-string-if-the-char-array-that-stores-it-is-smaller-tha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455302/where-c-really-stores-a-string-if-the-char-array-that-stores-it-is-smaller-tha)

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "Enter the second sentence: "<<endl;
```

Prints `Enter the second sentence:`  to the console.

```
cin.get(Sentence2,SIZE,'$');
```

Reads up to `SIZE - 1` number of characters, or until the first `$` character from console to `Sentence2` array (including space characters. 1 character reserved for the zero terminator).

```
cout << Sentence2 <<endl;
```

Prints `Sentence2` variable to console.

Comment: I can't understand that here we haven't input any Sentence2  so how can it work. Do u understand what I mean

Comment: @AshKetch the input is like a pipe. You enter "This is my first sentence" and this stays there until it is fully extracted. Firstly `cin >> Sentence;` reads only the first word, but the rest stays there. When you do `cin.get` it continues to read the rest of the characters from the pipe.

Comment: Ohh Okay I understood. Thank you for explaining .